# Unit test for my ViewModel?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm new to unit testing and I'm really stuck atm so I could really use some help.

**Some application info**
I have a WPF application in MVVM. It gets data from a database (classes generated via .edmx).
All linq queries are handled by methods in the Database class.
In CustomerListViewModel, it makes a list of all Customers to be shown in the CustomerListView.

**My problem**
I am new to Unit Testing. I've read about it and tried to make it work. But as I understand, it should/can be done without touching the DB. I tried to find as much info as I could, but it wouldn't work with what I have. And now I'm basically stuck.

**My question**
How do I unit test this piece of code? How can I know if I've successfully queried the database (with or without touching the DB in the unit test)?
(If I understand it for this piece, I can figure the rest of the classes and methods out on my own)

**The code**
CustomerListViewModel:

```
public CustomerListViewModel()
{
    MyObservableCollection<Customer> listCustomers = new MyObservableCollection<Customer>();
    ListCustomers = App.Database.GetCustomerList();
}

private void GetListCustomers()
{
    ListCustomers = App.Database.GetCustomerList();
    if (App.Database.hasError)
        App.Messenger.NotifyColleagues("SetStatus", App.Database.errorMessage);
}
```

Database:

```
public MyObservableCollection<Customer> GetCustomerList()
{
    hasError = false;
    MyObservableCollection<Customer> customerList = new MyObservableCollection<Customer>();
    try
    {
        QRM_Entities dc = new QRM_Entities();
        var query =
            from customers in dc.Customer
            select customers;

        foreach (Customer cust in query)
        {
            customerList.Add(cust);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorMessage = "GetCustomerList() error, " + ex.Message;
        hasError = true;
    }
    return customerList;
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want to unit test? As of now it sounds like you want to have a unit test for the sake of `having a unit test`. Not really sure if it makes sense to write a test for `GetListCustomer()` method on your `vm`, as it doesn't have any logic, other than making a call to some service and assigning returned value to `ListCustomers` property.
If you're using service locator in ur code - `App.Database`, it's going to make writing unit tests really hard/painful. Some ppl consider [service locator being an anti-patter](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)

Comment: @Michael, although I agree with your logic about not testing the `GetListCustomer()` method as it does no logic, the other side of that coin is what happens if someone replaces the first line with `throw new ArgumentException(@"I don't know what I'm doing.")`, unit testing would pick this up instantly. No matter how trivial the test will be we should be testing that the component is correct rather than just the parts that actually have logic.

Comment: @StephenRoss I'll just say that I don't agree with your justification - `what happens if someone replaces the first line with throw new ArgumentException(@"I don't know what I'm doing.")` to have a unit test for rather trivial methods. But this is never ending discussion and usually tends to endup in personal preferences.

Comment: To unit test *any* type of code, you have to break dependencies between a given class and all other classes.  These dependencies should be abstracted and injected, rather than hard coded. That allows you to replace them within a test with fixtures that you control and can inspect to determine if expectations were met. If you're starting out, there are lots of resources out there covering unit testing strategies and tools. Use your favorite search engine to find them. Also, look for a short book on the subject at amazon. Get it, read it. You won't regret it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way that you have the `ViewModel` currently setup will make it almost impossible to unit test.
The issue is on this line:

```
ListCustomers = App.Database.GetCustomerList();
```

I presume that `App` is a static and `Database` is the class that you are using as your Data Access Layer. So everytime that you call the constructor of your `CustomerListViewModel` you will call the actual `Static` implementation of `App` which you would have to setup before creating the View Model, meaning that you would always be testing with the actual Database, which is obviously what you are attempting to bypass.

In comes my favorite software principle the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), the premise of this is that decouple modules so that your high level module depends on an abstraction of a lower level module. And that details should depend on that abstraction. Effectively you should develop to an interface and provide this interface to dependents.

Taking your example I would extract interfaces for your database interaction and provide these to your View Model, but I'll go a step further and provide this to a model which will be provided to your view model.

IDatabase:

```
public interface IDatabase
{
    IEnumerable<ICustomer> GetCustomerList();
}
```

ICustomerListModel:

```
public interface ICustomerListModel
{
    ObservableCollection<ICustomer> Customers
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

CustomerListModel

```
public class CustomerListModel : ICustomerListModel
{
    private readonly IDatabase database;

    private readonly ObservableCollection<ICustomer> customers;

    public CustomerListModel(IDatabase database)
    {
        this.database = database;
        this.customers = new ObservableCollection(database.GetCustomerList());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ICustomer> Customers
    {
        get
        {
            return this.customers;
        }
    }
}
```

CustomerListViewModel

```
public class CustomerListViewModel
{
    private readonly ICustomerListModel customerListModel;

    public CusomterListViewModel(ICustomerListModel customerListModel)
    {
        this.customerListModel = customerListModel;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ICustomer> Customers
    {
        get
        {
            return this.customerListModel.Customers;
        }
    }
}
```

So what you can see here is that I have extracted an interface for the database which I request the information from, this means that I don't care about the implementation of the `IDatabase`, I just now that it provides me with a collection of `ICustomer`'s when I call `GetCustomerList()`.

So I `inject` a copy of the `IDatabase` into the `CusomterListModel` class which I can then query knowing that I'll get what I want back correctly. I then inject the `ICustomerListModel` into the `ICustomerListViewModel` so that the collection can be presented to the `View`.

So to test the `CustomerListModel` I would have a test like:

```
[Fact]
public void Customers_IsCorrectlyInitialisedAtStartup_Test()
{
    var databaseMock = new Mock<IDatabse>();
    var customer = new Customer();

    var customers = new [] { customer };

    databaseMock.Setup(mock => mock.GetCustomerList())
        .Returns(customers);

    var sut = new CustomerListModel(databaseMock.Object);

    Assert.Equal(customers, sut.Customers);
}
```

In this I have mocked a version of the `IDatabase`, now you can see how I don't care in the version of `CustomerListModel` what `IDatabase` I have as long as I can call `GetCustomerList()`. This has a setup to return a `ICustomer` when a call to `GetCustomerList()` is called. Finally I am asserting that the `Customers` collection was correctly populated with the returns of the `IDatabase` call.

Unit testing is a fine art, difficult to understand at first but when you get it working at first you'll pick it up quickly. Some things you may wish to look at to help you with generating unit testable code and actually testing:

- [Solid Principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), principles that every Software Engineer should at least be familiar with, will help generating code that is testable.
- [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), the wiki-page on Dependency Injection outlining the pros and cons to injecting the dependency into a constructor, when and how to use it in further examples.
- [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart), a friendly and easy to use mocking framework for C#, which I used as part of my example above.

Comment: Good answer, though I'd called `IDatabase` `ICustomerRepository` and `ICustomerListModel` feels like an abstraction too much. If it would contain logic it'd be rather `ICustomersService`, if it's plain CRUD one can directly use the repository

Comment: @Tseng yes I agree, if it were my own app it would probably be `ICustomerDal`, and yeah for the example the `model` was a little step further but I hate to see a `ViewModel` that would directly access a `DAL` for data. I wanted to keep it in line with what the OP had as I didn't want to stray too far from what they already have currently, but simply expand. If the consensus is to change to more "correct" naming I will, but I don't want to stray too far currently from the source material.

Comment: in the spirit of keeping test doubles to a bare minimum, I would strongly recommend against newing up a `Mock` object for ICustomer in this case, unless the concrete `Customer` class is really complicated to instantiate/has a bunch of annoying hard dependencies. `Customer` is probably (should be) a leaf in the object graph, it is mostly a waste of time to fake containers of data with some in-memory methods

Comment: @kai That's true, as I usually use AutoFixture I forget that it's probably better to simply new things up in tests sometimes than create mocks everywhere. I'll update to show this.